# Does Netbeans 'Test File' separate from 'Test'?

Tags: java, testing, netbeans, selenium, junit

I have several JUnit 4 Selenium tests in my project. When I run them singularly by choosing right click on test/Test File they pass. But when I choose right click on project/Test, all tests fail. Why is this? Are their run initialized different way somehow?

All my test classes inherit parent class:

```
 public abstract class TestBase extends UnitilsJUnit4 {

@TestDataSource
private DataSource dataSource;
private static ExtendedHtmlUnitDriver driver=new ExtendedHtmlUnitDriver(true);;
public IDatabaseConnection connection ;

public TestBase() {


}

@Before
public void setUp() throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException  {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(SeleniumConstants.IMPLICITY_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    Signin.signOut(driver);
    driver.removeHeader("uid");
    driver.close();

}

/**
 * @return the driver
 */
public ExtendedHtmlUnitDriver getDriver() {

    return driver;
}
```

Example of test:

```
@Test
public void myTest()   {
    getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/menu/site/search')]"));
```

Comment: Well, fail *how*? With what errors? Are they run in the same order each time? Do they fail at the same place each time?

Comment: The test line gives unable to locate node  exception. The order is same and place too.

Comment: The *full* stack trace please. Are you running these locally or against a remote server?